# Overriding == and != on a class

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

is there any way to do this on a class and still retain the capability to detect whether a variable of the Type is null ? I can do this for structs, (cause struct can't really be null, with a struct, instead of comparing x with null, you use a separate method caleld IsNull or HasValue... but you can't use that technique with a class cause when the class variable is null, of course, you can't call such an instance method on it !

```
public class myClass: IEquatable<myClass>
{
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public static bool operator ==(myClass cA, myClass  cB)
    { return cA is myClass && cB is myClass && cB.Equals(cA); }
    public static bool operator !=(myClass cA, myClass cB)
    { return !(cA == cB); }       
    public override bool Equals(object o) 
    { return o is myClass && this == (myClass)o; }
    public override bool Equals(myClass o) 
    { return IntValue == o.IntValue; }

}
```

but when I go:

```
myClass x;
if (x != null)    // this returns false when it should be true 
{
   //code to execute with x here
}
```

For what it's worth, the only reason I want this to be a class is because it participates in a simple inheritance relationship.  This is an immutable class, and in effect what I am trying to do here is code it so it can behave like an immutable and nullable class, exactly like an immutable, nullable struct behaves (such as `Nullable<int>` or `Nullable<float>` etc.

Comment: Just thinking aloud here, but what would be the disadvantage of always returning true in your overload when cA or cB is null?

Comment: The `is` operator calls in `public static bool operator ==(myClass cA, myClass  cB)
    { return cA is myClass && cB is myClass && cB.Equals(cA); }` are not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's why `IsNull` should be a static method taking a parameter. `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is a good example. After that, nothing prevents you from making it an extension method.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static bool IsNull(MyClass other)
    { return ReferenceEquals(other, null); }
    public static bool HasValue(MyClass other)
    { return !IsNull(other); }
    // other code
}

public static class MyClassExtension
{
   public static bool IsNull(this MyClass myClass)
   {
       return MyClass.IsNull(myClass);
   }
}
```

This will let you do the following without throwing:

```
MyClass myClass = null;
if(myClass.IsNull())
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Combine with @jjrdk's ReferenceEquals suggestion from below, I think this will work.. Thanks!

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I was hesitant in doing it myself so I +1 him instead. :) Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not initializing `x` so it is `null`, you need to do this

```
 myClass x = new myClass();
 if (x != null) {/* is true */}
```

Comment: Whether or not x is null, writing (x != null) calls the code in my operator override....

Comment: added more of the code to make this explicit... but the `!=` is NOT the standard .net `!=`.... It is running my override of `!=`. So whether the variable is or is not null has nothing to do with it. It is the code in my override that controls what the `!=` method will return.

Comment: yes but the `is` in your `==` comparisons fails because the second argument is `null`, I don't see why you expect a null check to return false when the object is `null`

Comment: yes, this was exactly the problem... How to check for null when every call to `==` or to `!=` was being rerouted to my overrides...

Answer (score 3):

You can always use:

```
ReferenceEquals(x, null)
```

this returns a boolean value showing whether x is null.

Comment: Wish I could check two answers as solutions,  your answer, combined with Coincoins from below ended up being the solution... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not do this at all.
2. You should only do this for an immutable class, if you really must. And then,
3. You should follow the [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: 1)  Thanks for your help.  2)  I need to do this.  3) This type is immutable.  4) Stay in your box with your guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class myClass: IEquatable<myClass>
{
    public static bool operator ==(myClass cA, myClass  cB)
    { return (cB == null && cA = null) || (cA is myClass && cB is myClass && cB.Equals(cA)); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just override GetHashCode and Equals?

when you override them both it allows you do do both == and != very easily..